# Call to a member function result() on boolean in CodeIgniter3, ms sql server

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, sqlsrv

im createing a website with my friend using CodeIgniter3 with ms sql server. When i try to  run the app on my local its work, but my friend not working and got this message on model.

```
Call to a member function result() on boolean in
```

and the cause of the error is this code

```
return $query->result();
```

i have the same sqlsrv, php version (8.1) and odbc driver (odbc17) version with my friend but different Microsoft Sql Server, so i wanna ask is the version of the ms sql server is the problem or the db connection of my friend is wrong?? also how to solve that error?? i already tried anything like `this->db->query("...")` or etc but still not working on my friend's local..

also here is the code of database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '1234567890', 
    'database' => 'project_event', 
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv', 
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' =>  (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Something has failed and `$query` is false. Whatever sets up $query, I assume is failing.

Comment: first, verify that your friend has sql server and enabled for access through ip (check through SQL Server Configuration Manager). next, ensure the credentials used to login to the db is correct.